# Django-CMS admin no css folder?

Tags: css, django, django-cms

I installed Django-CMS and my admin page doesn't display correctly because it is looking for CSS files in `/static/admin/css/`, but the admin folder in my install came with no .css files, and the admin page uses a .css file called `dashboard.css`, which exists nowhere in the django-cms download. Where am I supposed to get the .css and image files for the django-cms admin plugin?

Comment: you should use virtualenv and install django via pip , did you do it ?

Comment: How are you serving static files?